# From MySQL to SQL Server Migrating and Mapping Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mapping, database-migration

I have a running system on Java and MySQL. Moving the system to .NET environment. I also optimized the db tables on MS SQL which should be filled with the data from MySQL db. So i need to map the tables where to go because they are seperated now. How can i do that? What are the alternatives and the best way for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) (SSIS) is a great tool for migrating data between 2 points.  You can also use the [Import/Export Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) (right click the database, Tasks, Import Data) that is included in SQL Server as a starting point.

Comment: Well, I need to map the db's. They are not same tables and spesifications anymore.I'm not sure this will help me this time.

Comment: You can do that in SSIS.  That is the basic premise of ETL - extract, transform, load.  Declare the source (extract), apply any business rules to the load (transform), and map to the new destination (load).

Comment: I'm still not sure, because what is told to me is "use MySQLClient and create ModelMySQL then map to ModelSQL and insert into SQL Server". Don't get it as not trusting you but are you sure? :)

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL specific tools but SSIS is the standard when it comes to data migration for SQL Server related things.  It comes included in the SQL Server install so nothing extra is needed.